# Having more than one NavigationControllers in one application in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I want to use TabBar and wnat to also have more than one views.

But then is it possible to have one navigationController for each views?

I want keep track of views in each of them, and ofcourse it should display different navigationBar and views when I tab a new Tabbar item.

Is that possible? I could give it a try but I don't want to waste time. So if it's possiblt, I'm going to start to work.

Thanks to any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, yes, it's possible. :)

Longer answer: For each of the `UIViewController`s, you would instantiate a `UINavigationController` and set the `UIViewController` as the root view using `initWithRootViewController:`. You would then pass these `UINavigationController`s into the `UITabBarController` by setting the `viewControllers` property.

Comment: Oh you again(Korean). Appreciate for the exact and fast and detail answer! ;)